# Vue displays validation text on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There are two buttons called ADD and REMOVE. If the user clicks on ADD it will add one more input field for FULL NAME. I am using `validationText` to display text as `PLEASE ENTER MORE THAN 5 CHARACTERS` for full name. If I ADD two fields and insert only two characters in second one then it displays `validationText` on both input fields as

[image]

Is there a way to display `validationText` message to the particular field which consists of less than 5 characters?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="work-experiences">

      <div class="form-row" v-for="(minordatabase, index) in minorsDetail" :key="index">

        <div class="col">
          <br>
          <label id="minorHeading">FULL NAME</label>
          <input v-model="minordatabase.full_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FULL NAME" size="lg" @input="checkValidation"/>
          <p v-show="!validationText" style="color:red;">
           Please enter than 5 characters
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

      <br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button @click="addExperience" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-right:1.5%;">Add</button>
        <button @click="removeExperience" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Remove Last Field</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    minorsDetail: [
     {
       full_name: "",
       date_of_birth: "",
     }
    ],
    validationText: true
  },
  methods: {
    checkValidation(){
        console.log("SAN");
      var minorsDetailLastElement = this.minorsDetail[this.minorsDetail.length-1].full_name.length;
      console.log(minorsDetailLastElement);
        if(minorsDetailLastElement > 2){
        this.validationText = false;
      }
      if(minorsDetailLastElement > 5){
       this.validationText = true;
      }
    },

    addExperience(){
          this.minorsDetail.push({
            full_name: ''
          })

    },

    removeExperience: function(todo){

          var index = this.minorsDetail.indexOf(todo)
          this.minorsDetail.splice(index, 1)
          this.removeMinorFieldFunction();
    },

  }
})
```

Below is the code on `JSFIDDLE`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/5mqp1bag/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `validationText` for all fields. So, if you set it for one field, it's going to show up in the other field too.

I recommend doing something like this instead to show the validation:

```
<p v-if="minordatabase.full_name.length > 2 && minordatabase.full_name.length < 5" style="color: red;">
  Please enter more than 5 characters
</p>
```